# Is there a definition of an unpointed schematic homotopy type?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, stacks, simplicial-presheaves

In the paper Champs Affines (http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~btoen/chaff.pdf) Toen introduces pointed schematic homotopy types (SHTs) to solve Grothendieck's schematization problem (described in Pursuing Stacks).

I have been trying to learn the theory of schematic homotopy types, but there is one point which has consistently confused me in the literature:

Q: Is there a notion of an unpointed schematic homotopy type?

Every author I have read either works exclusively in the pointed case, or seems to implicitly define an unpointed SHT as a simplicial presheaf $F$  which is a pointed SHT for any choice of point $s:*\to F$. Is this the correct definition? If so, why do we always speak about pointed SHTs?

Comment: Isn't this the same as in the case of ordinary spaces? Lots of functoriality properties only work for based spaces in classical homotopy theory, although oftentimes when the spaces are connected CW-complexes, you can get away with omitting it.  I would expect that the schematic version is more delicate and the basepoint should be kept track of in all cases.